# Make the text in a table tiny and adjust the width of a table using the user package nicematrix

Tags: width, size, nicematrix

I am doing some tables for a cheat sheet.

My goal is to make a table with the text size `\tiny` (or smaller...) that the table ( `\usepackage{nicematrix}`) fit in a column that is `width = 0.23\textwidth` broad.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}


\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip} % paragraph layouts
\usepackage{fancyheadings}

\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{Seite \thepage} 
\rhead{Cheat sheet } 
\lhead{} 
\fancyheadoffset{0.01 cm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\newgeometry{top=0.55in,bottom=0.55in,right=0.3in,left=0.3in} 

\begin{paracol}{4}
\begin{small}

\begin{table}
 \tiny
\begin{NiceTabular*}{0.3\textwidth}{@{}>{\tiny}c*{3}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c}@{}}[colortbl-like]
\toprule 
\bfseries Ziel & \bfseries indirekte Hemmung & \bfseries Wirkstoff & \bfseries Applikation\\
\midrule
\rowcolor{lightmintbg}\Block{4-1}{AT-III}& F-X \& F-II & unfrakt. Heparin & s.c. / i.v.\\
\rowcolor{lightmintbg}& F-X $>$ F-II & niedermolek. Heparin & s.c. / i.v.\\
\rowcolor{lightmintbg}& F-X $>>$ F-II & Herparinoide &\Block{}{ s.c. / \\ lokal (Salbe)}\\
\rowcolor{lightmintbg}& F-X  & Fondaparinux& s.c.\\
\midrule
\Block{}{Vit. K Epoxid\\-Reduktase} & F-II, VII, IX, X & Cumarine & oral\\
\midrule
\rowcolor{lightmintbg}\Block{2-1}{F-X}&-& \Block{}{ Rivaroxaban,\\ Apixaban, \\Edoxaban }& oral\\
\rowcolor{lightmintbg}&- &Hirudin & i.v.\\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter
\end{NiceTabular*}
\end{table}

\end{small}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

As I am using  `\usperpackage{nicematrix}` you might need to download the newest version of trunk (or how you call it :) )
=> [www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty)

It should just look like this table.
[image: picGoal]

Comment: In my opinion, you should not use this font size in a table, unless you provide your readers with a magnifying glass…

Comment: I need id for a cheat sheet. It's not for any reader just for my exam and should just work to be in the row and therefore 0.23\textwidth. I know it's not very aesthetic

Comment: For me, it's not an aesthetic problem, but a problem of readability. The lower bound size,for me, would be \footnotesize. There are other ways to gain space, e.g. in tagles, reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` or `\arraycolsep`.

Comment: You mention wanting the table to be 0.23\textwidth wide but use 0.3\textwidth. Please clarify. Please also show the code and output of a tabularx table that has a smaller font. You mention an error message. Which one do you get?

Comment: I want to have 0.23 but in the code I sent I have 0.3 because otherwise I can not compile it right.

Comment: The code is not compilable as it currently is, regardless of the width you use since you declare a total of 5 columns but only use 4 of them. To make the code compilable, replace `*{4}` with `*{3}`.

Comment: Is https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj1yo.png closer to the expected output?

Comment: You would make your life a lot easier and your table probably better readable if you drastically reduced the margin sizes, for example by adding `margin=1cm` to the options of the `geometry` package.

Comment: @ leandriis: do you mean the margin size of the document or the table? because I reduced the marign size of my document to the minimum but I do not have the whole code here

Comment: I'm referring to the margin size of your document. This will at the same time increase the textwidth quite significantly leading to more space that is available for your table. Please include the corresponding setting in your MWE. How should others be able to make suggestions on how to fit your table into the available space if they don't know how much space there is?

Comment: I already reduced the margin size of my document. It's just that I have a certain amount of pages I can use for my exam. So I just need to reduce each element to a small size. And I just need to get the table in my column which is 0.23\textwidth

Comment: Please edit your question and show us how exactly you reduced the margin size of your document.

Comment: I did edit my quesiton. I hope its understandable :)

Comment: In your code, you use `landscape` as an option of the `geometry` package, but the use of `\newgeometry` with which you changed the margins results in a portrait page. Which orientation would you like to achieve? Please clarify. OT: Replace `fancyheadings` with `fancyhdr`.

Comment: I'm sorry that's the code that I use. I can not clarify it better. Otherwise I just use my screenshot. I see it makes too much truble. It doesn't seem something common.

Comment: I just pointed out an inconsistency in the code that severely influences the available width and thus asked for a clarification.  Do you want a landscape or a portrait oriented page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this table is closer to your goal.

Done with `nicematrix`, normal font and reduced to `0.25\textwidth`

[image: z]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}

\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
    \sffamily   
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} 
     \resizebox{0.25\textwidth}{!}{%    resize to 0.25\textwidth <<<<<<
        \begin{NiceTabular}{ *{4}{l} @{}}[hvlines, cell-space-limits=4pt,
            rules/color={white},rules/width=0.5pt,
            code-before= {\rowcolors{2}{lightmintbg}{gray!10}[cols=1-4,restart]},
            code-before= {\rectanglecolor{gray!25}{1-1}{1-4}},  % header row: \rectanglecolor{<color>}{<row ini-col ini>}{<row end-col end>} <<<< 
            ]
            \bfseries Ziel                       & \bfseries indirekte Hemmung  & \bfseries Wirkstoff                   & \bfseries Applikation \\
            \Block[fill=lightmintbg]{4-1}{AT-III}& F-X und F-II                 & unfraktionierites Heparin             & s.c.,  i.v.           \\
                                                 & F-X $>$ F-II                 & niedermolekulares Heparin             & s.c.,  i.v.           \\
                                                 & F-X $>>$ F-II                & Herparinoide                          & s.c.,  lokal (Salbe)  \\
                                                 & F-X                          & Fondaparinux                          & s.c.                  \\
            \Block{}{Vit.-K-Epoxid--Reduktase}   & F-II, VII, IX, X             & Cumarine                              & oral                  \\
            F-II                                 &                              & Debigatran                            & oral                  \\  
            \Block[l, fill=lightmintbg]{2-2}{F-X}&                              & Rivaroxaban, Apixaban, Edoxaban       & oral                  \\      
                                                 &                              &Hirudin                                & i.v.                  \\  
        \end{NiceTabular}
    }
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing! Yes :D

Comment: If I can ask one more thing: how do you get the numbers in \rectanglecolor{theColor}{?-?}{?-?}.

Comment: Thank for your feedback!. I upgraded the answer by adding some comments and simplifying the code.

There is only one `\rectanglecolor` left to repaint the header a darker gray.
 
The syntax is `\rectanglecolor{<color>}{<row_ini-col_ini>}{<row_end-col_end>}`, in this case, with only the first row and four columns, `\rectanglecolor{gray!25}{1-1}{1-4}}`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the assumption that you actually wanted to get a landscape oriented page, you could use the following code to squeeze the entire table into one of the 4 available columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}


\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip} % paragraph layouts
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{Seite \thepage} 
\rhead{Cheat sheet } 
\lhead{} 
\fancyheadoffset{0.01 cm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\newgeometry{top=0.55in,bottom=0.55in,right=0.3in,left=0.3in} 


\newlength{\firstcolwidth}
\setlength{\firstcolwidth}{\widthof{\tiny Reduktase}}
\newlength{\secondcolwidth}
\setlength{\secondcolwidth}{\widthof{\tiny F-X $>>$ F-II}}
\newlength{\thirdcolwidth}
\setlength{\thirdcolwidth}{\widthof{\tiny Fondaparinux}}
\newlength{\lastcolwidth}
\setlength{\lastcolwidth}{\widthof{\tiny s.c. / lokal}}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{4}
\begin{table}
 \tiny
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceTabular*}{0.24\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     Y{\firstcolwidth} 
                                     Y{\secondcolwidth}  
                                     Y{\thirdcolwidth} 
                                     Y{\lastcolwidth}}
\CodeBefore
\rowcolors{1}{lightmintbg}{}[respect-blocks]
\Body
\toprule 
\bfseries Ziel & \bfseries ind. Hemmung & \bfseries Wirkstoff & \bfseries Appl.\\
\midrule
\Block{4-1}{AT-III}     & F-X \& F-II      & unfrakt. Heparin                & s.c. / i.v.\\
                        & F-X $>$ F-II     & niedermolek. Heparin            & s.c. / i.v.\\
                        & F-X $>>$ F-II    & Herparinoide                    & s.c. /  lokal (Salbe)\\
                        & F-X              & Fondaparinux                    & s.c.\\
\midrule
Vit. K Epoxid-Reduktase & F-II, VII, IX, X & Cumarine                        & oral\\
\midrule
\Block{2-1}{F-X}        & -                & Rivaroxaban, Apixaban, Edoxaban & oral\\
                        & -                & Hirudin                         & i.v.\\
\bottomrule

\end{NiceTabular*}
\end{table}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

---

To squeeze the table into one of the 4 columns on a portrait page, you could use `\setlength{\lastcolwidth}{\widthof{\tiny (Salbe)}}` instead of the definition in the MWE and add `\setlength\columnsep{0.013\textwidth}` to the preamble of your document.

Comment: it looks very organized!Thank you I will learn from this